# Mixing QooXDoo and jqgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jqgrid, qooxdoo

I am trying to mix QooXDoo and jquery , jqGrid but i am just a qxd beginner ( i just downloaded yesterday) . as jqGrid is way more powerful , featureful than qxd's Table , i want to use it , plus current application is all build using jqgrid . (used about 75% of all its features) so i dont want to bother doing them in qxd.

Is they anyway , just to embed jqgrid directly into qxd? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at the qooxdoo mailing list:
http://qooxdoo.678.n2.nabble.com/jqGrid-and-qooxdoo-td5808285.html#none

Comment: I decided to rewrite everything in QxDoo and its working fine now!

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular javascript within a QX class. Therefore it should be possible to use other JS libraries too.

I suggest you to write a wrapper ([library](http://manual.qooxdoo.org/1.2/pages/tool/generator_config_articles.html#pages-tool-generator-config-articles-library-key-and-manifest-files) or even a [contribution](http://qooxdoo.org/contrib) [at lest you can have a look at this how the integration is done there]) for the jqGrid. After that you can easily use jqGrid within qooxdoo.

Using this jqGrid within QX may produce problems too: The UI is different and needs customization, you need to maintain the library and you have more dependences for your project. Perhaps you can have a look at the powerfull table-fetatues of QX and avoid using a redundant library.

Comment: I already obviously stated why i need jqgrid , not qxd's table, please read carefully. qxD's table is not even close to half of jqgrid yet. And my project already written (15k lines of 20 server side controllers) for jqgrid already , I am not going to use any other table solution. What need for jqgrid to work is a dom element with an id , and jqgrid can directly applied to it , jquery style.

Comment: I know it's possible to run other UI libs like jqgrid in qx, but it really does not make sense, it is like trying to use jqgrid in a desktop app, you can do it but it does not make sense. Good luck if you get it working, however your statement regarding it not having half the features is false and misleading to others. I have not found a single feature in jqgrid that can not be easily reproduced in qx.ui.table. You can also write your own model code to handle all of your data marshaling client side and avoid any changes to your backend services.

Comment: Really ? can you show me how to make a pager at Qooxdoo's Table ?Theres not even a single Pager avaliable in Qooxdoo table and would be not so easy to write one from scratch .. thats sad.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert in embedding other JS libs into qooxdoo apps, but there are several successfull attempts of doing so, so it shouldn't be too hard. E.g. have a look at [qxJqPlot](http://qooxdoo.org/contrib/project/qxjqplot) which wraps jqPlot for use in qooxdoo. You might want to look at the [code](http://qooxdoo-contrib.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/qooxdoo-contrib/trunk/qooxdoo-contrib/QxJqPlot/trunk/source/class/qxjqplot/Plot.js?revision=20802&view=markup) that wraps jqPlot. If that is not close enough to your use case, have a look at the other [contributions](http://qooxdoo.org/contrib/project), I'm sure you'll find one that uses a DOM element to embed library functionality.